# How to increase ROM size for sky mote in Contiki-OS, cooja simulation?

Tags: contiki

I want to use sky mote in my Cooja simulation so that I can access the full functionality of the collect-view tool such as power readings.

However I have had to port extra libraries for my project so the size of the program far exceeds the memory provided by the sky-mote.

Cooja-mote can support the program size as it uses native system but it won't provide me with power readings in collect-view.

How can I increase the ROM & RAM size of sky-mote for Cooja simulation without loosing power measuring capabilities. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't use TCP you can disable it with the variable UIP_CONF_TCP=0 and then save some space in both ROM & RAM.

Comment: Actually I need most of the functionality provided by a typical Contiki program. So increasing the size of ROM seems like the only option to me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be somewhat late, but I still hope it can help anybody digging here.

If you are using msp430-gcc and contiki-ng project (may be similar to the old version contiki, I'm not sure), the MCU model is defined at the [line 20](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/develop/arch/platform/sky/Makefile.common#L20) of `contiki-ng/arch/platform/sky/Makefile.common` by setting `MCU=msp430f1611`. And the link script of the model can be found at `msp430/lib/ldscripts/msp430f1611/memory.x` of [msp430mcu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/files/msp430mcu/) package you installed.

So you will see the memory map of the model in the file, and the rom region starts at 0x4000 and ends at 0xffe0, which is ~40KiB long.

You can simply change the MCU model in `Makefile.common` to msp430f169 to get a ~60KiB ROM, howerver the RAM shrinks to 2KiB. Or you can change the memory map to whatever you like.

**Unfortunately**, since msp430 is a 16-bit MCU, you will never get a memory address more than 64KiB with the internal memory, i.e. the total capacity of ROM and RAM can never exceeds 64KiB even if without interupt vectors and peripherals.

Besides, you also need to modify code in mspsim to make cooja to fit the new memory layout as Johan Bregell says. Things you are probably most interested with are in `tools/cooja/mspsim/se/sics/mspsim/config`, which sets address, and `cooja/mspsim/se/sics/mspsim/platform/sky/CC2420Node.java`, which sets the chip model of CC2420.

Comment: This is somewhat helpful... but the comment on 64k is not helpful in my opinion. Cooja supports `msp430x`. If you need more ROM, use an msp430x node that Contiki already has, instead of hacking msp430f1611 memory files where the marginal gain is very small.  If you still need more RAM/ROM, hack the memory files then - once I made a fake "Z1x" mote with 32KiB RAM myself in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to use another mote instead of `sky` (48 kb ROM). Contiki supports few more `msp430` architecture motes, such as Zolertia Z1 (96 kb ROM) and Wismote (up to 256 kb ROM).

Answer (score -1):

The definitions of the MCU the Sky mote is running on is in the folder `contiki/tools/mpsim/se/sics/mpsim/` from here you should be able to modify the amount of memory avalible to the MCU if you know your way around Java.