# Compilation error using rest and rime together in Cooja

Tags: c, rest, makefile, contiki, cooja

I am trying to create a ContikiOS firmware that acts as a gateway using Rime and REST. The gateway must communicate to other motes with the Rime mesh, and can communicate to the outside via a REST API.

The following code is a combination from two default Contiki examples (rest-example/rest-server-example.c and rime/example-mesh.c). Therefore I include "rest.h", "net/rime.h", "net/rime/mesh.h".

The problem is when I try to compile this firmware using following makefile, the rime files don't get included into obj_sky and any Rime functions I use in the firmware get an 'undefined reference' error. However when I remove the lines in the makefile and any code referring to REST in the firmware code, it does compile (and adds the rime files to obj_sky).

Would anyone have an idea why rime does not get added after adding the rest-http app and what I can do to have it compile?

Thank you

## Code

Compiler info

```
> make gateway.sky TARGET=sky 
  CC        gateway.c
  CC        ../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c
  LD        gateway.sky
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: gateway.sky section `.data' will not fit in region `rom'
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: section .vectors loaded at [000000000000ffe0,000000000000ffff] overlaps section .data loaded at [000000000000ff0c,0000000000010037]
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.6.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 88 bytes
gateway.co: In function `process_thread_init_mesh':
gateway.c:(.text.process_thread_init_mesh+0x10): undefined reference to `mesh_close'
gateway.c:(.text.process_thread_init_mesh+0x26): undefined reference to `mesh_open'
gateway.co: In function `recv':
gateway.c:(.text.recv+0x48): undefined reference to `mesh_send'
gateway.co: In function `enable_handler':
gateway.c:(.text.enable_handler+0x80): undefined reference to `mesh_send'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
../../Makefile.include:254: recipe for target 'gateway.sky' failed
Process returned error code 2
make: *** [gateway.sky] Error 1
rm obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o gateway.co
```

Makefile

```
all: gateway mote

ifndef TARGET
TARGET=sky
endif

CONTIKI=../..


WITH_UIP6=1
UIP_CONF_IPV6=1

WITH_COAP = 0

APPS += rest-http

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

Lines to compile for REST

```
WITH_UIP6=1
UIP_CONF_IPV6=1

WITH_COAP = 0

APPS += rest-http
```

gateway.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "contiki.h"
#include "contiki-net.h"
#include "rest.h"
#include "net/rime.h"
#include "net/rime/mesh.h"

#if defined (PLATFORM_HAS_LIGHT)
#include "dev/light-sensor.h"
#endif
#if defined (PLATFORM_HAS_BATT)
#include "dev/battery-sensor.h"
#endif
#if defined (PLATFORM_HAS_SHT11)
#include "dev/sht11-sensor.h"
#endif
#if defined (PLATFORM_HAS_LEDS)
#include "dev/leds.h"
#endif

#define DEBUG 1
#if DEBUG
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINT6ADDR(addr) PRINTF(" %02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x ", ((uint8_t *)addr)[0], ((uint8_t *)addr)[1], ((uint8_t *)addr)[2], ((uint8_t *)addr)[3], ((uint8_t *)addr)[4], ((uint8_t *)addr)[5], ((uint8_t *)addr)[6], ((uint8_t *)addr)[7], ((uint8_t *)addr)[8], ((uint8_t *)addr)[9], ((uint8_t *)addr)[10], ((uint8_t *)addr)[11], ((uint8_t *)addr)[12], ((uint8_t *)addr)[13], ((uint8_t *)addr)[14], ((uint8_t *)addr)[15])
#define PRINTLLADDR(lladdr) PRINTF(" %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x ",(lladdr)->addr[0], (lladdr)->addr[1], (lladdr)->addr[2], (lladdr)->addr[3],(lladdr)->addr[4], (lladdr)->addr[5])
#else
#define PRINTF(...)
#define PRINT6ADDR(addr)
#define PRINTLLADDR(addr)
#endif

#define MESSAGE "Hello"

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------RIME--------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static struct mesh_conn mesh;

PROCESS(init_mesh, "RIME Mesh");

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void
sent(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
  printf("packet sent\n");
}

static void
timedout(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
  printf("packet timedout\n");
}

static void
recv(struct mesh_conn *c, const rimeaddr_t *from, uint8_t hops)
{
  printf("Data received from %d.%d: %.*s (%d)\n",
     from->u8[0], from->u8[1],
     packetbuf_datalen(), (char *)packetbuf_dataptr(), packetbuf_datalen());

  packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
  mesh_send(&mesh, from);
}

static void
send(int to, char * msg)
{
    printf("Sending data to %d", to);
    rimeaddr_t addr;
    packetbuf_copyfrom(msg, strlen(msg));
    addr.u8[0] = to;
    addr.u8[1] = 0;
    mesh_send(&mesh, &addr);
}

const static struct mesh_callbacks callbacks = {recv, sent, timedout};
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(init_mesh, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_EXITHANDLER(mesh_close(&mesh);)
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  mesh_open(&mesh, 132, &callbacks);
  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------------------------REST-------------------------------------*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
RESOURCE(enable, METHOD_GET, "enable");
void
enable_handler(REQUEST* request, RESPONSE* response)
{
    int moteId = 0;
    char moteIdstr[12];
    sprintf(moteIdstr, "%d", moteId);
    char command[20];
    char responseText[255];

    if (rest_get_query_variable(request, "moteId", moteIdstr, 10)) {
    PRINTF("moteId %s\n", moteIdstr);


        send(moteId, command);


        sprintf(responseText,"Command execute for mote %s!\n", moteIdstr);
  } else {
    sprintf(responseText,"Mote not available!\n");
  }


  rest_set_header_content_type(response, TEXT_PLAIN);
  rest_set_response_payload(response, (uint8_t*)responseText, strlen(responseText));
}

PROCESS(gateway_rest, "Gateway Rest");
PROCESS_THREAD(gateway_rest, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

#ifdef WITH_COAP
  PRINTF("COAP Server\n");
#else
  PRINTF("HTTP Server\n");
#endif

  rest_init();

  rest_activate_resource(&resource_enable);
  //rest_activate_resource(&resource_disable);

  PROCESS_END();
}

/*---------------*/
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&init_mesh, &gateway_rest);
```

## Info

I am using Sky motes to compile the code in Cooja.

Comment: Your code does not fit into the flash memory of Sky. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107134/how-to-increase-rom-size-for-sky-mote-in-contiki-os-cooja-simulation