# net/rime.h error using Cooja, how can I install it but not just download it?

Tags: c, include, broadcast, contiki, cooja

I am trying to do a simple simulation in Cooja (literally the example on the Contiki website [here](http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a00009.html#a5)).

However I have an error message linked to my #include "net/rime.h", Cooja outputs the following message while compiling:
*fatal error: net/rime.h: No such file or directory*

I thought that it came with Contiki when I've installed contiki-ng following the procedure on the official website. My quick fix was to download the file from the github repository and store it in my active directory. However I find it quite ugly, is there a way to install this library ? Because I haven't found a way yet.

Thanks a lot.

It's a question close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044288/compilation-error-using-rest-and-rime-together-in-cooja).

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of method are you using to start Cooja? Directly on the SO? Over Docker?

I recommend you de Docker way, and remember to apply the command

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

after cloning the git repository.

Also, if you are using Docker, check if the binding of the Contiki folders between de Host and the Container are correctly made.

Comment: I am using Docker, thanks for you answer.