# failing on running coffee file system example on Wismote in Contiki

Tags: c, filesystems, contiki, cooja

I want to test an example of cfs Contiki on Wismote. I used the example here:
[Coffee filesystem example](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Coffee-filesystem-example)

This example works well on sky mote. when I want to implement on Wismote I change the target to Wismote and here is the makefile :

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = [project_name]
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

#UIP_CONF_IPV6=1
CONTIKI_WITH_RIME = 1   CFLAGS =-DUIP_CONF_IPV6
MODULES += core/net/ipv6/multicast

ifeq ($(TARGET),avr-raven)
COFFEE_FILES = 4
endif 

CONTIKI =../../../
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

After compiling, I get this error message :

> /usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: cfstest.wismote section `.data' will not fit in region`rom'
>   /usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: section .vectors loaded at [0000ff80,0000ffff] overlaps section .data loaded at [0000fe82,0000ff81]
>   /usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 2 bytes
>   contiki-wismote.a(cfs-coffee.o): In function`cfs_coffee_get_protected_mem':
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to`xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pwrite'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to`xmem_erase'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to`xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to`xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pwrite'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to`xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pread'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to`xmem_pwrite'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pwrite'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to`xmem_pwrite'
>   /home/user/contiki/examples/mySim/Dscv/../../..//core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c:1369: undefined reference to `xmem_pwrite'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   rm cfstest.co obj_wismote/contiki-wismote-main.o
>   make: *** [cfstest.wismote] Error 1
>   Process returned error code 2

I checked core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c to see the code in line 1369, but as you can see in [cfs-coffee.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/cfs/cfs-coffee.c), there was not such a line.
Does anyone has any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: I think you may have two problems. You have a lot of undefined symbols that are `xmem_*`. But, also, your `.data` section is too large to fit in available ROM. For some help, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107134/how-to-increase-rom-size-for-sky-mote-in-contiki-os-cooja-simulation A search on "xmem_pwrite" yielded this page which has the source code for the `xmem_*` functions: https://dak664.github.io/contiki-doxygen/a01226_source.html

Comment: thank you for your advices. I hold my data in two char arrays which was defined as message[32] and buf[100]. I changed them to message[1] and buf[1] but I've got the error again. I'm new to contiki and c. I searched for symbols but could not get any clue to follow to understand what you meant. would you please giude me more about undefined symbols which are xmem_* ?

Comment: `xmem_*` is just a shorthand for (e.g.) `xmem_pread` and `xmem_pwrite`. These [missing] functions are defined in the contiki source in files of the form: `platform/blah/dev/xmem.c` where `blah` can be one of: `native`, `wismote`, `z1`, or `sky`. For some reason, either they aren't built into `contiki-wismote.a` or it's not finding the ones that are built. Try running the correct version of `nm` on your `.a` (e.g. `/path_to_cross_build_tools/nm contiki-wismote.a`). You should see a `xmem.o` in the output [that defines the symbols with type `T`

Comment: thank you very much. you are right. there is no xmem.o file in contiki-wismote.a . I'm trying to follow the instructions to solve the problem.

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm really appreciate for your advices, would please explain the way I can find the correct version of nm? I am using contiki 3.0 on ubuntu 12 on vmware workstation 14. I wanted to add xmem.o to contiki-wismote.a so in platform/wismote/dev directory, I tried gcc xmem.c, I got compiler error which says that "contiki.h" is not defined. is there any way that I can get xmem.o file for wismote?

Comment: How exactly you build the code? `examples/cfs-coffee` builds very well for `TARGET=wismote`.

Comment: well there was no cfs-coffee file in examples folder so I was not aware of that but I found it here : [https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/cfs-coffee/example-coffee.c]. thank you.